# Accept variable number of arguments and execute them

Tags: bash

I need a bash function to accept variable number of arguments. These arguments are other commands like `ls /root`, `echo HI`, `git clone http:// ....`, `rm` etc. The function executes the commands sequentially

The function must accept the arguments as:

```
myfun <arbitrary set of commands>
```

Note that each command may have an arbitrary set of parameters for itself.

```
myfun echo H ls /root git clone http://.... /home/myh/git/x1
```

myfun should execute as follows

```
echo H
ls /root
git clone http://.... /home/myh/git/x1
```

The way arguments are passed to `myfun` can be changed. Is there a way to achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: Why do You need function for that? You can just separate commands by `;` (comma), bash will then run them one by one.

Answer (score 1):

You can *sort of* do this but, as [Michal Przybylowicz suggests](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1155607/accept-variable-number-of-arguments-and-execute-them#comment1922493_1155607), you shouldn't. If you *know* you want to do this, you could skip ahead; otherwise, please consider these alternatives.

- If your goal is to issue multiple commands on one line that run one after another, separate them by `;`.
- If you you want them to run at the same, separate them by `&`. this will run them all in the background except the last one. If you want the last one to run in the background, put a `&` after it, too.
- If you want them to run one after another but stop when one fails, separate them by `&&` instead of `;`.
- If you want to be able to apply redirects to the while block of commands, enclose them in `{` `}`. You need a space after the opening `{`. The closing `}` must either appear on a new line or have a `;` before it. Apply the redirections after the closing `}`, on the same line. For example, `{ echo H; ls /root; } >out.txt`.
- If the reason you want your function to run its arguments as commands is that you want to do *other* things with the arguments, then this *might* be reasonable, but you should consider alternatives. If you want to keep track of them, and the commands are being entered interactively, then you may be able to use the shell's own history facilities; see `help history` and `help fc`. If you want to immediately show the commands that will be run as well as run them, use `set -x`; see `help set` for details.

The reason you should not usually write a function that runs each of its arguments as a full command is that it would be cumbersome and error-prone to use such a function, because you would have to quote each argument that consists of multiple words (i.e., that passes one or more arguments to a command). This might not seem so bad... until you realize some of your arguments might themselves have needed quoting anyway, in which case you have to quote the quotes, too. This is workable, but far from ideal.

As a concrete example of the problem, consider the command you suggested you might be able to run to invoke your function:

```
myfun echo H ls /root git clone http://.... /home/myh/git/x1
```

That won't work. How is `myfun` supposed to know where one command ends and the next one begins?

---

If you *really* want to do it, one reasonable approach is to use the `eval` builtin (see `help eval`). Call the function whatever you like, it doesn't have to be named `eval_all`:

```
eval_all() { for cmd; do eval "$cmd"; done; }
```

`for cmd` has the same effect as `for cmd in "$@"`. Use whatever name you like for the `cmd` variable; just remember to change `$cmd` accordingly. If you want to avoid writing to a `cmd` variable used outside the function:

```
eval_all() { local cmd; for cmd; do eval "$cmd"; done; }
```

However you decided to write this function, if you wanted to use it to run the commands `echo H` and `ls`, you would call it like this:

```
eval_all 'echo H' ls
```

But you can already do this, which is nicer:

```
echo H; ls
```

If you also wanted it to run the command `touch 'honest $$$$ ideas.txt'`, you would call it like this:

```
eval_all 'echo H' ls 'touch '\''honest $$$$ ideas.txt'\'
```

There are other ways to quote single quotes. None of them are especially pretty. None are nearly as nice as:

```
echo H; ls; touch 'honest $$$$ ideas.txt'
```